# Swapping bits in a positive 32bit integer in C#

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation

So I'm trying to solve this problem:

> You are given random 32bit positive integer, and what you have to do is swap the values of the bits on 3rd, 4th and 5th positions with those on 24th, 25th and 26th position.

Comment: Assuming you're truly stuck at the beginning. Tools you will need: bitwise AND (`&`), bitwise OR (`|`), left shift (`<<`), and right shift (`>>`). Other than this, post what you've tried that doesn't work.

Comment: It's not homework in the real sense of the word, I'm self-educating myself and ask Q's which I can not answer myself. I'm well aware that I need to use bitwise operators but in this case I just don't see the solution, so I decided to look for a help.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that it is not "homework" as such. Can you at least post what your thoughts are about how you would solve it? If you explain this is for self-education as well, people won't be so quick to assume.

Comment: I don't want to get involved in such kind of discussions just need help for this problem - I know all the tools that I need to resolve just don't know how to use them correctly. I thought that maybe if I see a working solution it will clarify at least a little how the different bitwise operators are used to accomplish such kind of tasks.

Comment: @lc read the description of the homework tag. Please don't add it anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that this is a problem for which you do not want an explicit solution, here is a hint: mask the bits in question using `&`, do a shift, and then `OR` then in using bitwise `|`.

You can "cut out" bits 3, 4, and 5 using the `0x00000034` mask, and bits 24, 25, and 26 using the `0x07000000` mask.

Take a look at this [solution](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ReverseParallel) to bit reversing problem for an inspiration.

**EDIT :** (in response to "not a homework" comment) Since this is not a homework, here is a more in-depth explanation:

```
unsigned int val = ... // your value
unsigned int bits_03_04_05 = val & 0x00000034;
unsigned int bits_24_25_26 = val & 0x07000000;
// Cut out "holes" at bits 3, 4, 5, 24, 25, and 26 of the original value
unsigned int res = val & ~(0x00000034 | 0x07000000);
// Put bits 3, 4, and 5 in place
res |= bits_03_04_05 << 21;
// Put bits 23, 24, and 25 in place
res |= bits_24_25_26 >> 21;
```

Comment: Thanks, gonna need time to understand completely your solution but I think this is what I needed to keep on. Thanks.

Comment: @Leron It might be worth mentioning that this answer starts to count bits with position 0, while Marc Gravell's answer starts to count with position 1.

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
    // snag the values from 3,4,5 (small) and 24,25,26 (large)
    int small = value & (7 << 2), large = value & (7 << 23);

    // remove the old values, and add in the new ones
    value = (value ^ (small | large)) | (large >> 21) | (small << 21);
```

(which counts bit 1 as the LSB; if you mean bit 0 is the LSB, then adjust the numbers by 1)

Comment: +1 Very cute! Especially the "`XOR` to clear" trick. Since you cleared out the bits, the last `^` can be replaced with `|`, right?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight hmmm, yes I guess so!

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem you use the properties of the bitwise `operator&` and `operator|` by applying them between the initial integer value and a [mask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_(computing)).

Assuming you have an initial value:

```
 unsigned int val;// your value
```

you need to form a mask:

```
int setLSB = 1;   // 00000001

int atPosition = 4;

// shift the set bit 4 positions to the left
int mask = setLSB << atPosition;   // 00010000
```

and then use it to retrieve, clear and set bit value:

```
// get bit at position 4
unsigned int valueOfFourthBit = val & mask;

// clear bit at position 4 and assign to result
unsigned int res = val & ~(mask);

// put the value of the 4th bit at wanted position
int wantedPosition = 21;
res |= valueOfFourthBit << wantedPosition;
```

---

If you need a range of consecutive bits, as in your case 3, you can do:

```
int numberOfSetBits = 3;
int setLSBs = 0

for (int i =0; i < numberOfSetBits; ++i)
{
    setLSBs += (int) Math.Pow(2, i);
}

setLSBs = 7; // 00000111

// and then the masks for getting 3,4,5 and 24,25,26 bits become
int smallPosition = 3;
int largePosition = 24;

int smallMask = setLSBs << smallPosition; // 0x00000034
int largeMask = setLSBs << largePosition; // 0x07000000;
```

The rest is covered in the existent answers.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I don't like with the given answers is that they are all hardcoded. This is a more generic solution:

```
int s32_Value = XYZ;
s32_Value = SwapBits(s32_Value, 1<<3, 1<<24);
s32_Value = SwapBits(s32_Value, 1<<4, 1<<25);
s32_Value = SwapBits(s32_Value, 1<<5, 1<<26);

int SwapBits(int s32_Value, int s32_Mask1, int s32_Mask2)
{
    bool b_Bit1 = (s32_Value & s32_Mask1) != 0;
    bool b_Bit2 = (s32_Value & s32_Mask2) != 0;
    s32_Value &= ~s32_Mask1;
    s32_Value &= ~s32_Mask2;
    if (b_Bit1) s32_Value |= s32_Mask2;
    if (b_Bit2) s32_Value |= s32_Mask1;
    return s32_Value;
}
```

This function can also be used with enums that contain bit flags. For example if you want to swap the Anchor of a System.Windows.Forms.Control from Left to Right and vice versa:

```
Ctrl.Anchor = (AnchorStyles)SwapBits((int)Ctrl.Anchor, (int)AnchorStyles.Left, (int)AnchorStyles.Right);
```

This is the definition of the enum:

```
// Specifies how a control anchors to the edges of its container.
[Flags]
public enum AnchorStyles
{
    // The control is not anchored to any edges of its container.
    None   = 0,
    // The control is anchored to the top edge of its container.
    Top    = 1,
    // The control is anchored to the bottom edge of its container.
    Bottom = 2,
    // The control is anchored to the left edge of its container.
    Left   = 4,
    // The control is anchored to the right edge of its container.
    Right  = 8,
}
```