# C# - How to swap the value of the nth value of a string?

Tags: c#

```
   Console.WriteLine("Please enter a decimal number:");
   int decNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 

   string binary = Convert.ToString((long)decNumber, 2); 
   Console.WriteLine("\n" + "The binary conversion of the number {0} is: {1}", decNumber, binary);

   Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Please select a bit position: ");         
   int position = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

   Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Please select a new value to replace the old one: ");
   int newValue = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

Hello,

Basically what I want this program to do is convert a decimal number to binary and then replace a nth in position value of the binary representation. 
I really tried all sorts of things, but I just can't seem to find an elegant solution that actually works. Additional explanation would be helpful and no, this is not my homework.

Comment: This is homework !!

Comment: Is a decimal number an integer or a decimal (which is float)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990093/how-to-change-nth-element-of-the-string

Comment: @Akash Kava

Well, it really is not. I am trying to teach myself C# and I have been stuck for the past 2 hours on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
    char newValue = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(binary);
    sb[position] = newValue;
    binary= sb.ToString();
```

Comment: That's, cool. Thanks!

Is there a method to do that but only for the selected position?

Comment: yes if you want to replace for all occurrences . just do binary.Replace(binary[position], newValue);

Answer (score 0):

Swapping bits in a integer involves some complex logical operations [Swapping bits in a positive 32bit integer in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413356/swapping-bits-in-a-positive-32bit-integer-in-c-sharp), but [`BitArray`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray) can make it a **bit** easier:

```
static int swapBits(int i, int position1, int position2)
{
    // convert int i to BitArray
    int[] intArray = { i };
    var bitArray = new System.Collections.BitArray(intArray);

    // swap bits
    var bit1 = bitArray[position1];
    bitArray[position1] = bitArray[position2];
    bitArray[position2] = bit1;

    // convert bitArray to int i
    bitArray.CopyTo(intArray, 0);
    i = intArray[0];
    return i;
}
```

Note that the positions start from 0 and from the right, so for example

```
int i = swapBits(3, 0, 2);  // 3 becomes 6
```