# How to get bit values from byte array using shifting with 32 bit big endian mask in C#

Tags: c#, mpeg2-ts

I have a four byte array (which represents an MPEG TS packet header) and I want to get PID value which is 13 bits starting from bit 12 to 24 (in bold). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_transport_stream) says the PID value has a 32-bit Big Endian Mask... what does that mean?

0100 0111 000**0 0101 0011 0100** 0001 1101

I understand that the first byte or eight bits is 0x47 because there are 8 bits...

128  64  32  16 8 4 2 1

0    1   0   0  0 1 1 1

0x47 is 71 or 64 + 4 + 2 + 1...

How do you parse bit values inside the byte array that are not 8 bits and/or embedded across bytes??

Comment: Is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413356/swapping-bits-in-a-positive-32bit-integer-in-c-sharp the type of answer?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yes, that is what I am looking for...I want to use shift and mask

Comment: use the [bitwise operators](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_bitwise_operators.htm) to shift bits and mask them. Big endian means that the high order byte is first, e.g. 0xA0B70708 will consist in the A0 B7 07 08 byte sequence in big endian and gives 08 07 0B 0A in little endian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first taken from Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Big

> The most significant byte (MSB) value, 0Ah, is at the lowest address.
>   The other bytes follow in decreasing order of significance. This is
>   akin to left-to-right reading in hexadecimal order.

Therefore your bits in the array are in the right order, you just need the value.
You can create an integer by taking the first byte (ignoring the first 3 bits), shifting it by 8 bits and then adding the second byte.

```
byte[] packet = new byte[4];
int value = ((0x1F & packet[1]) << 8) | packet[2];
```

Which gives 0x0534 (101 0011 0100) for your example. Then you can compare this value to the ones listed on Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

This would work for any size of byte array:

```
public static bool CheckIfMaskBitIsSet(byte[] mask, int bit)
        { 
            int bitPerByte = bit % 8;
            int byteIndex = bit > 0 ? (bit / 8) : 0;
            if(mask.Length>byteIndex)
                return ((mask[byteIndex] >> bitPerByte) & 1) == 1;
            return false;
        }
```